# Is it possible to find two distinct 4-colorings of the tetrahedron which use exactly one of each color?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring, polya-counting-theory

I'm working on a problem for Discrete Math, and I'm having some trouble. The question is:

Determine the pattern inventory for red/green/blue/yellow colorings of the vertices
of a regular tetrahedron.

(a) How many distinct 4-colorings are there?

(b) Is it possible to find two distinct 4-colorings of the tetrahedron which use exactly
one of each color? Explain.

I've already completed part a (and by extension, I have the pattern inventory completed). The answer should be 36.

But I'm having trouble with part b. I'm not sure that I understand the question, or how to work it. Maybe I've overlooked something. Could someone help me out, please?

EDIT: The pattern inventory should be:

1/12[(r+b+g+y)^4 + 8(r+b+g+y)(r^3+b^3+g^3+y^3) + 3((r^2+b^2+g^2+y^2)^2]

Comment: A rephrasing of (b): is it possible to color two tetrahedra so that each one has a single face of each color, and so that you can distinguish the two tetrahedra by the way they are colored (even if you can rotate them?)

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is a guess: would it be like coloring one tetrahedron in all four colors, and then trying to make a second one in its mirror image? So rotating it wouldn't work, making them distinct?

Comment: By "distinct" I guess you mean indistinguishable under the rotation group. With a palette of $4$ colors, the number of distinct vertex colorings with no restrictions is $(8\cdot4^2+3\cdot4^2+1\cdot4^4)/12=36$ by Burnside's lemma. With the restriction that each color be used once, this becomes $(8\cdot0+3\cdot0+1\cdot4!)/12=2$ so the answer to (b) is yes. To see this "by inspection", set the tetrahedron down on a table with the yellow vertex on top; the red, blue, and green vertices can be in clockwise or counterclockwise order.

Answer (score 0):

For b you need to determine if reflections are different or not.  There are four vertices, so if you use all four colors you have one vertex of each color.  If you color them on two tetrahedra, put the tetrahedra on a table with the red vertex up, you can have green/blue/yellow go clockwise on one and counterclockwise on the other.  These are the same if reflections are allowed and not if they are not.